# TABLE_DATE_RANGE difficulties in Google BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Examples from the Google BigQuery cookbook involving TABLE_DATE_RANGE don't work in the preferred "Standard SQL" although they work in the older "Legacy SQL".
Example of the Legacy SQL-style command.

```
FROM (TABLE_DATE_RANGE([73156703.ga_sessions_], DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -7, 'DAY'), DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -1, 'DAY')))
```

I used back ticks (`) to enclose the table name instead of the legacy-style square brackets, but it fails with cryptic message

```
Error: Table-valued functions are not supported
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a [wildcard table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables) instead of `TABLE_DATE_RANGE`, which is specific to legacy SQL. An example is:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT *
FROM `your_dataset.ga_sessions_*`
WHERE PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', _TABLE_SUFFIX) BETWEEN
  DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND
  CURRENT_DATE();
```

You can read more about differences between legacy and standard SQL in the [migration guide](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql).

Answer (score 1):

For Standard SQL you need to write as this example:

```
FROM `google.com:analytics-bigquery.LondonCycleHelmet.ga_sessions_*`
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20130910' AND '20130910'
```